# Missing data from network monitoring graphs

Tags: networking, charts, network-monitoring

The graphs cacti is producing are incomplete. What is problem?

[image: graph]

Comment: You're missing data.

Answer (score 2):

This would be occurring because the CACTI graphs have got periods where there is no information.

You have not advised what data is being lost - so the rest of this post is speculation -

Most likely this is to do with dropped packets, ie "[data retrieval](https://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/operating_principles.html#DATA_RETRIEVAL)" is failing.  If this is SNMP related, your router could be under load (or shaping packets) and dropping the UDP requests.

Its also possible that your cacti install is spending to long getting data it is not completing runs in time.  In this case you might want to look at Spine - which is, I believe, a parallelized method of getting data from remote sources.

I'm pretty sure Nagios has logging which can give you some hints as to where the failures are.